# Django only submitting csrf token in forms?

Tags: django

So, I have this in my template:

```
<form action="./validate_code/" method="POST">
    {% if error %}
        <p>Sorry, that wasn't right.</p>
    {% endif %}        
    <label for="class_code">Your class code: </label>
    <input type='text' id='class_code'/>    
    <input type="color" id="color"/>    
    {% csrf_token %}    
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Which compiles to:

```
<form action="./validate_code/" method="POST">
    <label for="class_code">Your class code: </label>
    <input type='text' id='class_code'/>    
    <input type="color" id="color"/>    
    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='tGA4jKF1pd1QFC6NSAM9eNFvZqss0r4m' />    
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

And when I click submit, firefox sends this parameter:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken:"tGA4jKF1pd1QFC6NSAM9eNFvZqs60r4m"
```

That's it. No text, no color. I have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of your fields have a `name` attribute, so the browser sends no data.

You should really be using Django's forms framework for this, though.

Comment: This is just a quick password like thing. I didn't want to make a full form for that.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, you need to specify a "name" attribute in your input fields. You don't need to use Django forms, but if you are submitting the form normally, any fields you are expecting to be sent need to have a name.

```
<form action="./validate_code/" method="POST">
    {% if error %}
        <p>Sorry, that wasn't right.</p>
    {% endif %}
    <label for="class_code">Your class code: </label>
    <input type="text" name="class_code" id="class_code">
    <input type="color" name="color">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```